# Thread-safe warning when executing maven parallel build

Tags: maven, maven-3, mojo

I am running Maven parallel build. I am gettting some warning.

```
[WARNING] *****************************************************************
[WARNING] * Your build is requesting parallel execution, but project      *
[WARNING] * contains the following plugin(s) that are not marked as       *
[WARNING] * @threadSafe to support parallel building.                     *
[WARNING] * While this /may/ work fine, please look for plugin updates    *
[WARNING] * and/or request plugins be made thread-safe.                   *
[WARNING] * If reporting an issue, report it against the plugin in        *
[WARNING] * question, not against maven-core                              *
[WARNING] *****************************************************************
[WARNING] The following plugins are not marked @threadSafe in my-project:
[WARNING] org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.1.1
[WARNING] org.codehaus.mojo:cobertura-maven-plugin:2.2
[WARNING] ****************************************************************
```

The build is success. Can some one tell me which version of the following plugins will be threadsafe.

Can I simply ignore this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5` and `org.codehaus.mojo:cobertura-maven-plugin:2.5.2` are both threadsafe (from https://maven.apache.org/plugins/)

Mostly this warning is nothing to worry about, but I recommend using a threadsafe version for your plugins if you are using the parallel build feature.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. can you tell where can I get whether the plugin is thread safe or not. I also have few other plugins that are not threadsafe.

Comment: I manually search the plugins at https://maven.apache.org/plugins/ and http://mojo.codehaus.org/ and verify if the goals of that version are tread safe. For example: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/clean-mojo.html ;under attributes it states :"The goal is thread-safe and supports parallel builds."